# Counting inside an if/else statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, counter

I have a log in page, where users are asked to enter a code. I want to count how many times the users enters the wrong code, and if it is more then 3 times, show a page telling them to restart the processes, but my counter only outputs 1, even though I type the wrong code multiple times.

```
<div class="container">


<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center">
    <p>A code has been sent to your email</p>
    <p>Please consult your email to proceed with the login</p>
</div>

<form class="form-signin"  method="post">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Enter code</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="partnerEmail" value="<?php echo $_POST['partnerEmail']; ?>">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="partnerCode" placeholder="Code">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Accept</button>

</form>

</div> <!-- /container -->

<?phpsession_start();echo $_SESSION['partnerEmail'];?>

<div class="container">

<?php
include_once "conn.php";

$partnerCode = $_POST['partnerCode'];
$partnerEmail = $_SESSION['partnerEmail'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM partners WHERE partner_email='$partnerEmail' AND 
partner_login_code='$partnerCode' AND partner_active ='yes'";


$counter = 0;
echo $counter;

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" align="center">
          <p>Congratz - You logged in successfully!</p>
          </div>';


}
else
{
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" align="center">
          <p>ERROR - Please consult your email for the correct code!</p>
          </div>';

    $counter ++;
    echo $counter;

?> <script> $(".alert").effect("shake");</script> <?php
}

echo $counter;
?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You need to seperate this `<?phpsession_start()` if that is your actual code. `<?php session_start()`

Comment: I am not trying to update a query. I am trying to count how many times the else statement is passed.

Comment: What about `<?phpsession_start()` is that your actual code? As I stated already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to store the $counter value.

first the line who says:

```
$counter = 0;
echo $counter;
```

it can be transformed to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['counter']) && $_SESSION['counter'] > 0){
 $counter = $_SESSION['counter'];
}else{
 $counter = 0;
}
```

The part that says

```
$counter ++;
```

become

```
$counter ++;
$_SESSION['counter'] = $counter;
```

And then you can access it on other pages (as long as them are php and can access the sessions variables).

Answer (score 1):

Php is stateless. You are overwriting counter every time the page is loaded.
Instead save counter into session:

```
//$counter = 0; this is overwritting, replace with:
$_SESSION['counter'] = isset($_SESSION['counter']) ? $_SESSION['counter'] : 0;
//assigned by reference, changes to $counter will change $_SESSION['counter'] also
$counter = &$_SESSION['counter'];
```

As well as the above, you also appear to be starting the session **after** outputting html. This will not work, as starting a session requires sending an http header, which must be done before sending the http response (eg html)

Answer (score 0):

U could save a counter in your $_SESSION array and just increase the value anytime a user enter the wrong code. After a certain value is reached u can do something different inside your code.